# Menu dropdown - transformar <ul><li> em <select><option>

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gostaria de colocar o menu *dropdown* no meu site na hora de escolher as variações. Tanto no mobile quanto no computador.

Eu achei esse artigo ensinando a fazer, mas no script eu não consegui substituir corretamente os termos de CSS e HTML.

O script que eu usei:
https://css-tricks.com/convert-menu-to-dropdown/

Site com dropdown modelo:
https://www.madrugaosuplementos.com.br/100-whey-protein-2270g-optimum-nutrition-multishaker-gratis/

Meu site:
https://www.imperiodosuplemento.com/molho-de-tomate-grape-organico-todos-os-sabores-lergurme

O script que estou adaptando para meu site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Create the dropdown base
$("<ul />").appendTo("atributo-comum");

// Create default option "Go to..."
$("<option />", {
   "selected": "selected",
   "value"   : "",
   "text"    : "SELECIONE..."
}).appendTo("atributo-comum ul");

// Populate dropdown with menu items
$("nav a").each(function() {
 var el = $(this);
 $("<option />", {
     "value"   : el.attr("href"),
     "text"    : el.text()
 }).appendTo("nav select");
});

$("nav select").change(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
</script>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a fazer funcionar?

Comment: Cara pq vc simplesmente não da um display none no menu e um display block no select quando a tela for menor?

Answer (score 0):

Mas precisas de jquery para obter o efeito dropdown?
Apenas media query (css) resolve teu problema;

Teu layout quebra em 768px, precisa trocar a disposição dos elementos neste ponto:

@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
.menu.superior {
 /*...*/
}